# Keycloak. Проблема авторизации

Tags: java, vue.js, keycloak

Всем привет!

Разрабатываем приложение, в котором есть 2 фронтенда (один публичный, другой внутренний для компании) юзаем Vue. И один бэк, он общий для 2-ух фронтов (Java EE). Приложение состоит из 3-ёх модулей: core, public, private. Эти модули собираются в один ear.

Для авторизации используем Keycloak. У нас их 2. Первый - наш, используем для авторизации в публичном фронте. Второй - keycloak компании, для внутреннего фронта.

Возникла проблема, невозможно залогиниться сразу в двух фронтах. Если после деплоя первым залогиниться на паблик фронте, то логин пройдет успешно, данные с бэка подтянутся и весь функционал фронта будет доступен. Но при авторизации на прайвет фронте возникнет трабл: логин пройдет успешно, но при обращении на бэк возвращается 401 ошибка (Unauthorized).

И наоборот, если первым залогиниться на прайвете, то паблик будет возвращать 401 ошибку.

Возникает ощущение, что контейнер начинает использовать первый вызванный keycloak как дефолтный и проверяет токен другого keycloakа, не находит этот токен и возвращает 401...

Может у кого был схожий опыт...

Буду благодарен, если подскажете куда копать и что читать.

Заранее всем спасибо!